# Group by an item in a nested array using laravel collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, group-by, collections

I have an array that has the variable name **$array** and it is as follows:

```
$array = [
    "data"=> [
        [
            "company"=>[
                "id"=> 1,
                "name"=> "company1"
            ],
            "reports"=> [
                "active_reports"=> 3,
                "completed_reports"=> 2
            ]
        ],
        [
            "company"=>[
                "id"=> 2,
                "name"=> "company2"
            ],
            "reports"=> [
                "active_reports"=> 6,
                "completed_reports"=> 1
            ]
        ],
        [
            "company"=>[
                "id"=> 2,
                "name"=> "company2"
            ],
            "reports"=> [
                "active_reports"=> 7,
                "completed_reports"=> 5
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

So, I want to group this array by the company id. The **id** can be found in the nested array with key **company**

My expected result is below:

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "company1"
      },
      "reports": {
        "active_reports": 3,
        "completed_reports": 2
      }
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "company": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "company2"
      },
      "reports": {
        "active_reports": 6,
        "completed_reports": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "company": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "company2"
      },
      "reports": {
        "active_reports": 7,
        "completed_reports": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I tried the following logic:

```
foreach ($array['data'] as $data) {

   $reportsData = collect($data)->groupBy($data['company']['id']);

   Log::info($reportsData);
}
```

But this is the result I'm getting after trying the above logic:

```
[
  {
    "": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "company1"
      },
      {
        "active_reports": 3,
        "completed_reports": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "company2"
      },
      {
        "active_reports": 6,
        "completed_reports": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "company2"
      },
      {
        "active_reports": 7,
        "completed_reports": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to get the expected result as illustrated above.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a value to `groupBy` currently not a 'column' to group by. Though you have nested data here so you will need to pass a callback to `groupBy` where you will return what value the entities should be grouped by:

```
collect($array['data'])
    ->groupBy(fn ($item) => $item['company']['id']);
```

Or simply using the 'dot' notation (as mentioned by Donkarnash), since we are starting the collection at the 'data' key:

```
collect($array['data'])->groupBy('company.id');
```

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods -](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) `groupBy`

Comment: I guess the dot notation will also work here. Since the desired output doesn't require to manipulate the key, callback is not strictly required, dot notation should suffice `collect($array['data'])->groupBy('company.id');`

Comment: Yes it works in this way @Donkarnash

Comment: @Donkarnash yea it will, i forgot to retest that, i had tested it on the original array but not one starting at the 'data' key, works fine ... good call